# azure-cli login getting "self signed certificate in certificate chain"

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I have installed azure-cli via `npm install -g azure-cli` but and am getting `self signed certificate in certificate chain`:

[image]

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the these  bug reports it seems that this issue is related to npm using a system/network wide proxy which intercepts the SSL traffic. Update npm config with the https proxy and this issue should be fixed. some have reported that updating npm also has fixed it. check it out.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7519

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6916

Comment: The issue this user is seeing, is with Azure CLI and not NPM per se. NPM was only used to install Azure CLI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use troubleshooting guide for the Microsoft Azure Explorer tool for same issue https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4021389/storage-explorer-troubleshooting-guide.

It helped me, with only one tweak needed: openssl command should check connection to management.azure.com and not microsoft.com

So, the command in OpenSSL console will be:

OpenSSL> **s_client -showcerts -connect management.azure.com:443**

I have found a self-signed certificate in my case (subject = issuer) added by my company IT department. After importing that certificate into ASE (so that ASE can trust that self-issued cert) the problem was solved.